# Using topological sort to find inconsistencies represented by cycles in directed graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, graph-traversal, dag

Consider the following scenario.

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a group of cars that all drive from some point A to some point B. Each car starts driving in index order. i.e. $x_1$ starts driving strictly before $x_2$ and so on. i.e. Each $x_i$ starts driving strictly before $x_j$ for any $j > i$.

We also have a set of facts $Y$. We have that $(x_i,x_j) \in Y$ where $i < j$ if $x_i$ finishes driving before $x_j$ begins.

We also have a set of facts $Z$. We have that $(x_i,x_j) \in Z$ where $i < j$ if $x_i$ and $x_j$ were ever driving at the same time on the road.

The following is an example of an inconsistent pair of sets of facts $Y$ and $Z$.

If $Y = \{(x_1,x_2)\}$ and $Z = \{(x_1,x_3)\}$, then this pair of sets of facts are inconsistent. Why? We have that $x_1$ finishes driving before $x_2$ begins driving and we have that $x_1$ and $x_3$ were also at one point both driving at the same time.

But we know that $x_2$ begins driving strictly before $x_3$. So if $x_1$ finishes driving before $x_2$, then we also must have that $x_1$ finishes driving before $x_3$. Hence, we cannot have that $x_1$ and $x_3$ were also at one point both driving at the same time.

Hence, this pair of $Y, Z$ are inconsistent.

In general, consistency is defined so that for every $(x_i,x_j) \in Y$ where $i < j$, there is no $k \geq j$ such that $(x_i,x_k) \in Z$.

**Problem Statement**: Given $x_1,...,x_n$, where each $x_i$ starts driving strictly before $x_j$ for any $j > i$, and given $Y$ and $Z$, is all our facts consistent with each other?

I am looking for a general algorithm that can determine whether or not a given pair of $X,Y$ are consistent or inconsistent.

I am trying to formulate this as a directed graph problem where each node is some $x_i$, and each edge is some relationship given by elements of $Y,Z$. And then use topological sort to check if cycles exist.

My main issue is somehow translating $Y$ and $Z$ into edges of a directed graph.

The following problem is similar to my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702780/efficient-algorithm-to-check-queue-consistency-by-pairwise-relationship

Comment: (I find stackexchange.com [questions to work better](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) where there is one explicit question in the post body.)

Comment: What's your question?  I don't see a question here.  We are a question-and-answer site, and we require you to articulate a specific question.  Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?

Comment: I have edited the question to add some clarity. I hope it is clear. And the problem is an exercise on directed acyclic graphs (DAG) and topological sorting.

Comment: Where did you encounter this exercise?  Can you cite/credit the original source?